# How to change Swift header("ProductModuleName-Swift.h") Product name as product name changes dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, bridging-header

I am including the swift class inside `objective-c` class using the header `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`, where `ProductModuleName` is my application product name, hence it works fine!.

But the problem is, in my project i have an automation which will change the product name dynamically. I am having `xcconfig` file to override the build settings. In this case how to import the `"ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` dynamically as the product name changes from the automation

Please help!

Answer (score 9):

found the solution!

I tried by changing in build settings "Objective - Generated Interface Header Name" to be constant rather than the dynamic then it is working irrespective of the product name.

say i changed that file name as "Test-Swift.h" in build setting and imported the same in my project. This works irrespective of the product name.

Comment: Or `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME = Test-Swift.h` if you use .xcconfig files